# Phonegap project can't connect to server - Cors

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cordova, wamp

I'm developing a phonegap app with the use of HTML5, Css, Javascript and I need to connect my project to a server by using Ajax requests (i use phpmyadmin database on wamp server). I solved CORS problems by using the dataType="jsonp" in my ajax requests but they still don't work and the chrome console is not showing any error.
As an example, my sign-up form doesn't insert a new record in mydb:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/signup.js"></script>

<form id="regForm" action="" method="post" >
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname"/>
                <input type="text" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" placeholder="Date of Birth"/>

                <input  type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/> 
                <input type="submit" id="reg-button" name="signup" value="Sign up"/>
                <p id="signup-response"></p>
            </form>
```

Ajax requests:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#regForm').submit(function(){
        var form = $(this);
        responseMsg = $('#signup-response');
        //show response message - waiting
        responseMsg.hide()
                   .addClass('response-waiting')
                   .text('Please Wait...')
                   .fadeIn(200);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/myproject/signup.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success:function(data){
                //setup variables
                var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    changeClass = '';

                //response conditional
                switch(responseData.status){
                    case 'error':
                        changeClass = 'response-error';
                    break;
                    case 'success':
                        changeClass = 'response-success';
                    break;  

                //show reponse message
                    responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                               .addClass(changeClass)
                               .text(responseData.message)
                               .fadeIn(200,function(){
                                   //set timeout to hide response message
                                   setTimeout(function(){
                                       responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                                           $(this).removeClass(changeClass);
                                       });
                                   },3000); 
                                });
                     });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Signup.php:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000/");

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "mydb";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
      $nome = $_POST['name'];
      $cognome = $_POST['surname'];
      $birth = $_POST['birthdate'];
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      $query = "INSERT INTO user (name, surname, birthdate, username, password) 
              VALUES ('&name', '&surname', '&birth','&username', '&password')";

      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

      if($result){
          $msg = "User created";
          echo "ok";
      }else{
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
      }

  }

  mysqli_close();

?>
```

Can you please help me with finding the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 10.0.2.2 IP to connect your localhost from ajax call when u building phnegap peoject

in your ajax ULR do like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://10.0.2.2/myproject/signup.php',
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's giving me connection timeout error

Comment: ho wait ... i will check it

Comment: use this IP 127.0.0.1 and see

Comment: and also change in ur PHP code `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: I tried with 127.0.0.1 and header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); but  doesn't work, i guess it's the same thing i wrote above.. then i tried again with 10.0.2.2 and this is the error: 
GET http://10.0.2.2/myproject/signup.php?callback=jQuery1113093155223410576…&username=&password=&_=1449595083067 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: make sure u had put ur wamp server online to put online u need to right click on wamp icon which u see in bottom task bar

Comment: Are you using a Content Security Policy meta tag?  Also are you waiting for the deviceready event before doing your Ajax query?  This is different from the document ready event.